# For React / Redux, if the user merely clicks to see to different components / containers using React Router, then how can the app state be changed?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

Example, if the app state is

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  allPosts: PostsReducer,
  post: PostReducer
});
```

When the user clicks on one post in the list of all posts (the index), and see one post (with the PostsShow container), and then the user clicks "Back to Index" and then click on a different post, *now* imagine if the network is slow or jammed up, the user will actually see that previous post, because `state.post` is never changed yet, before the AJAX can fetch data.

In fact, all the user's actions were done by `<Link to="..." />` by `react-router`.  Is there a way to set the `state.post` back to `null` when the user clicks on "Back to Index" in the single post page (using the single post container), or, is there any other method that can accomplish the goal of not showing the previous post?

Comment: have you tried componentWillUnmount?

Comment: is it to call an action creator inside of `componentWillUnmount()`? So we need a new action such as `CLEAR_POST`? So maybe we can even think of it this way: whenever we need to change app state, think of an action, created by an action creator, and just think of where the action creator can be invoked.

Answer (score 0):

May be a little bit stupid, but:

```
render(){
  return(
    this.props.params.post_id != this.props.post.id ? <LoadingMessage /> : <PostPage />
)}
```

Comment: I thought of this method... but what if the user himself or another user modified or deleted the post, then... with network error, this method will show the old content as if the post is like that (instead of the new version). I think the app might be better just to show "Loading..." instead of showing wrong data. See... (1) if network ok, show correct data after 0 or 2 seconds, after showing the wrong data (2) if network down or slow, then show the wrong data and stop there, or show the wrong data for the first 7 seconds, and then show the correct data... I'd rather (2) doesn't happen